# Play subtitle on online streaming movies

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-player, subtitle

I want a player which can play subtitles while I am watching online movies.

I have tried VLC network streaming. It's not happening.

Well, there is a Windows app called [Greenfish Subtitle Player](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/Greenfish-Subtitle-Player.shtml), which allows me to play subtitles on top of my browser, but it is not available for Ubuntu. Is there any software like this ?

Edit: I have found a similar question but it is from 2012 and doesn't quite fit my requirement: [Subtitle players like Greenfish](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998675).

Comment: VLC actually fits your requirements (see the answer below). You might be experiencing a particular issue with the software that may need a dedicated question, or better still, [a bug report](https://wiki.videolan.org/Report_Bugs).

Comment: thanks for your response. But i was wondering if there was any "subtitle-player like Greenfish Player" and since there can some overhead works while playing online videos on vlc i would prefer it to be simple.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "overhead works while playing online videos"?

Comment: sorry i have explained this overhead below your answer.

Comment: VLC is the real solution if you take a closer look at it. Greenfish is in windows and not that reliable. I have edited the VLC answer with the links you need to add the proper stream address to VLC and possibly to other external players that also support subtitles (tested in Windows with PotPlayer, MPC, etc you may want to try SMPlayer in linux). VLC would also **download** the subs for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and then come up with an open-source cross-platform subtitle player, **Penguin Subtitle Player**. It works in the same way as greenfish but it works well also on Linux and OSX so one can play srt files on top of a web browser (or whatever).

- Download: https://sourceforge.net/projects/penguinsubtitleplayer/
- Source: https://github.com/carsonip/Penguin-Subtitle-Player

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is actually VLC, it indeed [shows subtitles on streaming videos](http://www.computerandyou.net/2013/04/how-to-watch-online-streaming-videos-with-subtitles/).

Just add the streaming video address by going to ***Media*** > ***Open Network Stream*** and then follow these steps:

- Click ***Play*** to start reproducing the video
- Right click in the video and select ***Subtitle*** > ***Open File...***
- Browse the file system to the appropriate `.sub` file and click ***Open***

Subtitles should then appear.

---

**EDIT**:

VLC will play the stream if it has access to the real URL of the video, which is not so obvious on all websites.
To get the proper URL stream, take a look at the answers under **[this question](https://superuser.com/q/114196/162573)**. To just start a video in an external player like VLC (using a Firefox addon that finds the proper URL), take a look at **[this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/819188/162573)**.

VLC will even **download** the subtitles for you - look at [**this answer**](https://superuser.com/a/573446/162573).

Comment: Exactly !! this is the very first thing i did. But it seems vlc just kept ignoring my demands just like my boss.

Comment: to be precise when i add a link to a open network Stream in vlc and play.Nothing happens. It works fine for certain websites but not for all.

Comment: If you found a bug with the software then file a bug report.

Comment: i would not call it a bug. Suppose i want to play a file from putlocker.bz first i would have to go the movie page, then view source, find the movie source file (if possible) ...and then add this to vlc streaming option.

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand what you problem is. You asked for a player that reproduces subtitles with streaming videos and I provided an answer. Now you are talking about some mysterious "overhead" related to VLC. If you have difficulties using VLC please post a new question detailing your issue.

Comment: This is the best answer, because VLC (and other players) will administer much better subs than Greenfish. VLC will even [download subs](http://superuser.com/a/573446/162573) for you. Even when VLsub addon gives an error the sub is in fact downloaded. VLC will play the URL stream on the condition that somebody sends that to it. as you said, that does not happen all the time. to solve this, take a look [here](http://superuser.com/a/814780/162573) and (my favourite) [here](http://superuser.com/a/819188/162573).

Comment: I know the exact problem of @ansuman and I have came out with the best solution now. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When the automatic search of subtitle of your player don't work for wished language, go to http://opensubtitle.org.

You always got the syncronized subtitle for the right CODEC of stream. This is the repository used by Popcorn-Time service.

Just load on VLC as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i will answer this myself ;)

### Player like GreenFish subtitle player

Well i didn't find any other player like greenfish on Ubuntu but you can still run greenfish in Ubuntu using wine.

for those of you who don't know what is wine:

> Wine is a free and open source software application that aims to
>   allow applications designed for Microsoft Windows to run on Unix-like
>   operating systems

Using this you can run greenfish or any other player like Titledrome to play subtitles on top of your browser.

See this for wine installation and configuration : [Wine](https://winehq.org/)

### Easiest Way

As @Luís de Sousa mentioned you can use VLC player.
Read Above answer

Comment: please check my answer for an updated solution in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely give [Substital](https://substital.com) a try.

It is a browser extension I created for Chrome and Firefox that will let you add subtitles on online streaming movies. I am myself using it on Ubuntu.

It's easier than VLC since you won't have to worry about finding the stream URL. If the video player on the web page is supported (and it supports many common video players used in streaming), then it's just easy! Once it is loaded in the video, you can directly search and load your subtitles from it. If needed you can even synchronize your subtitles with a slider, in live, while watching.

Answer (score 0):

Use website The Subtitles

For example, if you choose OpenLoad as your online video player, the page with the movie will look like the image below:

Let us take as an example the movie [*Flight* (2012)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTgPz.jpg)

To add subtitles to the movie, click on the "CC" button - this is a button in the bottom right corner of the video player.

[image: CC button in toolbar highlighted]

There will pop-up two possible selections: **Load srt/vtt from PC** and **Load srt/vtt from URL**. In our case, for the subtitles to load fast, you need to click **Load srt/vtt from URL**.

After that the invitation: **Please enter the Url of the .srt file You want to use** appears.

To enter the requested URL, please utilize the The Subtitles website: find the requested subtitles for the movie (eg *Flight* (2012) on the The Subtitles website and click the button <kbd>Copy Url</kbd>. As soon as the copying is completed, you will see in the right upper corner the notification **Url Copied**.

Go back to OpenLoad Player and insert the copied Url in the bar below the invitation: **Please enter the Url of the .srt file You want to use** and click <kbd>OK</kbd>

When you do this, subtitles start showing immediately. Enjoy your favorite movies with OpenLoad and TheSubtitles!